# Can't manipulate object model in an input ember after using each-in loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ember.js, each

[image]I created an input with pre-populated data. When I make changes to the input, i dont see the model changes like it should.

I have and object model like this below:

```
export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return {
      name: 'foo',
      height: '5ft',
      address: 'bar'
    }
  }
});
```

In my template, I am looping over using an each-in

```
{{#each-in model as |key value|}}
  <li>
    <label for={{key}}>{{key}}</label>
    {{input id=key value=value}}
  </li>
{{/each-in}}

{{model.name}}
// Still shows up as "Foo" even if i change it in the form input
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work with these changes:

```
{{#each-in model as |key value|}}
  <li>
    <label for={{key}}>{{key}}</label>
    {{input id=key value=(get model key)}}
  </li>
{{/each-in}}
```

https://codepen.io/kszambelanczyk/pen/rKGVzy?page=1&